# How to compress video file to 3gp or mp4 in java?

Tags: java

i am having a video file which i need to convert to 3gp, mp4 using java.

is there any library to do this or any sample ?

if any of you have done or know the sample please guide me to do the above or provide me the example.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you MUST use Java, check Java Media Framework.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool like `ffmpeg` ([ffmpeg.org](http://ffmpeg.org/)) or `mconvert` (from [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html)) or [VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode). You can call them from Java using the `ProcessBuilder` or [Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/exec/).

Answer (score 1):

You may have look at [pandastream](http://www.pandastream.com/). But it is a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Compressing video in java you can use IVCompressor
is very easy to use 
for more details go https://techgnious.github.io/IVCompressor/

simple code

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.techgnious</groupId>
        <artifactId>IVCompressor</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

public static void main(String[] args) throws VideoException, IOException {
    IVCompressor compressor = new IVCompressor();
    IVSize customRes = new IVSize();
    customRes.setWidth(400);
    customRes.setHeight(300);
    File file = new File("D:/Testing/20.mp4");
        compressor.reduceVideoSizeAndSaveToAPath(file,VideoFormats.MP4,ResizeResolution.R480P,"D:/Testing/Custome");
    }
```